# Keep one, service class related to the same functionality for two projects or create two, for each one

Tags: c#, architecture, layer

**Scenario:** I have two projects in one solution for sending emails. One project is library which allow to save email into database. Second one is a windows service app, which process that emails by sending them and doing some other operations on them. For this scenario lets call them Core & WS.

**Structure:** App(Core,WS) -> Service -> Repository -> Database

**Problem:** I want to keep everything clear and in the best practises. For now I have one Service layer which process emails. Actions are simple: AddEmail, GetAllEmails, MarkAsSent. So more all of this actions are related to the same table in db. It's just one Service class. So I am sharing that service through Core & WS. However I wondering if that is a good approach? Because I want to someone who will use my Core will have clear situation. He will need only use one method 'AddEmail'. Rest of them are related with WS and he don't need to bother about them.
I created Web Application and referenced Core library, then I used this AddEmail method. But I am able to use other methods as well.

**Questions**
 1. Should I split this service class and repository class for: CoreService, CoreRepository, WsService, WsRepository? If so I will resolve my problem but then I will have logic for the same functionality (email queue - the same table) separated on two projects. I am trying to create repository per classes. Then I will have two the same services in different project but with different set of methods. 
 2. What would I do if I wanted to add another WindowsService. The one which will only need to use GetAllEmails method. For instance to display all emails to send on the monitor. Should I then create for this service third project? And then by third time the same kind of service but with only one method? That would be even a duplication comparing to WindowsService service class. Like below:

*WindowsService (for processing emails)*: EmailQueueService.cs -> GetAllEmails,  MarkAsSent, MarkAsFailure..
*WindowsService (emails queue for display)*: EmailQueueService.cs -> GetAllEmails.

On the other case, everything shared by three different projects like now, doesn't look like a proper solution.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hi @codeedward. Can you summarise the problem as well. Not in terms of what each class needs to do but in terms of what you want to achieve in the end.

Comment: Of course @PreetSingh. However it's not that easy to summarise that in two sentences because my question is complex, but I can try recap everything. I want to have two applications - class library (named Core) & windows service (named WS). Should they share the same service class or should I create two separate service classes - each one in every of them? More details about problem in the root post.

Answer (score 1):

@codeedward, If i have understood your problem correctly, you basically have a Class that manages emails -

> AddEmail, GetAllEmails, MarkAsSent.

you have a web application where you want to expose just the **AddEmail** method, and don't want to see the other methods and vice-versa when it Comes to WS. In a situation like this, if you are the library author (person that will create and maintain the email service class) and have no control how it will be used you can simple rely on encapsulation, meaning you should hide your implementation details.

In practical terms, you can have 2 interfaces, one that just exposes **AddEmail** and another that exposes the rest of the methods. you can implement both of the interfaces on the same core service class. After this you can now just expose these interfaces out from your library(class library project), keeping the core service ( one that implements these interfaces) hidden and only visible within the Core project/Dll/library.

Your calling code can now take dependency on which ever interface they need and that technique/design principle is "Dependency inversion".

Hope this answers your query

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However if I hid the concrete class and made it visible only in my library I wouldn't be able to use IoC in any different project which want to contain this lib, because it wouldn't see this class. Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Comment: @codeedward, didnt quite understand the comment. Would you not have the lib containing the implementation/s referenced in the project you referenced the interface?

Comment: That's right. I want to disallow Project1 which reference Mailer to use any methods from WS and allow only to use these from Core. If repository layer is common and I will restrict this class as internal, I wouldn't be able to create it in my bootstrap container. In there I need to create <IClass,Class> where Class is concrete implementation. Since this implementation is common but internal I can't type it explicitly. I can't because Project1 is different than referenced Core library. If that make any sense?